# How do I count if a string is within the substrings of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```
list_strings = 'dietcoke', 'dietpepsi', 'sprite'
```

Here's what I did:

```
count = 0
list =
for ch in list_strings:

    if ch == sub:
        count += 1
```

`print((list_strings, 'diet') == 2)` is suppose to return `True` but it returns `False`.

Comment: To debug a bit, remove the `== 2` part and see what it's returning for various example inputs you can think of.

Comment: what is `sub`!?

Comment: my bad, in my function sub = diet

Comment: You don't seem to have a function. You're making a tuple then comparing it for equality to an integer, which is bound to fail. Also `==` won't tell you whether a string *contains* some substring. I'd recommend a basic tutorial, see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F.

Comment: Your code does not run at all.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood you correctly.

Just use `in` to check if your substring is present in the mainstring.

```
list = ['dietcoke', 'dietpepsi', 'sprite']
```

Your function should look like this:

```
def myfuncname(list_strings, sub_string):
    count = 0
    for ch in list_strings:
        if sub_string in ch:
            count += 1
    return count
```

If we call count now, we get `count == 2`

```
>>> print(myfuncname(list_strings, 'diet') == 2) 
True
```

Hope that solved your problem.